# PHP remove specific numbers from MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode, implode

My db is structured like:

```
id  |  posts |  groups
----+--------+-----------
1   |   10   |  2
2   |   30   |  2
3   |   20   |  2
4   |   50   |  2,8
5   |   54   |  2,8
```

When a user gets to 50 or more posts I want the script to remove the group '2'. There is already a prior script that adds the '8'.

I have this:

```
$cusstring = mysql_query("SELECT `groups` FROM `users` WHERE `postnum` >= 50 ");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($cusstring);

$array = explode(',', $row[groups]);
$pos = array_search('2', $array);
unset($array[$pos]);
$row[groups] = implode(',', $array);

mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `groups` = $row[groups] WHERE `postnum` >= 50 ");
```

It just doesn't seem to update though. I don't know if this is because it picks up multiple fields in the array or if I'm doing something wrong with the greater than or equal to symbol.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I've worked out that if I change the symbol to equal to the query works on the first row it comes across with a post count of 50 but it leaves the rest. It would appear it's only able to process one row.

Comment: `select id, groups`  and `update ....where id = $row['id']`

Comment: I will suggest trigger in your mysql, I can make one for you it will runs directly in your mysql database. let me know if you want that

Comment: When the user gets to `50` the value should only be `8`? `UPDATE \`users\` SET \`groups\` = 8 WHERE \`postnum\` >= 50 `

Comment: @chris85 not necessarily. Since it may have other non-related groups as-well. The 8 gets added when the user reaches 50 posts and the 2 group should get removed. Which is why I can't just re-write over the field.

Comment: @maytham I'd prefer to keep it all within the PHP.

Comment: @splash58 tried it. Still nothing happening :(

Comment: you will reduce scripting and querying between server and database server using trigger, but that is fine.

Comment: I've worked out that if I change the symbol to equal to the query works on the first row it comes across with a post count of 50 but it leaves the rest. It would appear it's only able to process one row.

Comment: You should fix your data structure to have a proper `UserGroups` junction table and not to store numbers in a coma-delimited string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would work for you. I think a SQL approach would be more efficient but you've said you want to keep it in PHP.

```
$cusstring = mysql_query("SELECT `groups`, `id ` FROM `users` WHERE `postnum` >= 50 ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cusstring)) {
    $groups = mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace('~(^|\s+)2(,|$)~', '', $row['groups']));
    //regex demo https://regex101.com/r/eX7qD1/1
    $id = (int)$row['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `groups` = '$groups' WHERE `id ` = $id ");
}
```

Your code is only getting one record because you aren't looping the fetch.

Also don't put data that comes from your DB back into a query directly this can lead to a SQL injection. Note I cast the `ID` here to an int and escaped the `groups` value. This should prevent the possibility of an injection.

You should switch drivers to `PDO` or `MYSQLI`. Once using one of those drivers you can use prepared statements.

This solution also will put an empty value in the groups field if 2 was the only value.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: I have a problem. When the group field is: "8,9,2" and I run the script the value it updates with is: "9,2". Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No space between the `,` and the `2`. The regex checks for whitespace before the 2 or if it is the start of the string. Is there any other group with a `2` in it aside from `2`? Example is `12`, `22` etc groups?

Comment: Use the regex101 link in the comments and you can see what is occurring. You could change the `\s+` to `\s*` which makes the whitespace optional and would work for the instance you described but it would change  `9,12,8` so that there was a straggling 1.

Comment: Currently theres no other group with 2 in it, just the group 2 itself. So if the field reads "8,9,2", without spaces, this solution won't work?

Comment: Just saw the new comment. I'll test that out to see what you mean by the straggling 1.

Comment: You could make the regex really loose and just be `2,?` which would replace any 2 and an optional comma after it. I usually prefer my regexs to be stricter than that though. If you update in the future and forget to fix this could run into some big problems..

Comment: That sounds ideal. What would the line of code be for that?

Comment: The \s* works well except when the 2 is at the end e.g. "8,9,2" since there is no trailing comma it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84330/discussion-between-chris85-and-ben).